# Setting mainfont and sansfont unsets CMU Bright as math font; how to fix?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I would like to be able to use a custom TTF (News Gothic) as the main font throughout my document wherever text occurs, and CMU Bright for math. But `\text` inside math mode should use New Gothic. However, attempting to use News Gothic as the main font unsets CMU as the math font, which you can see in the image below — `sin` is written in News Gothic, as is the `ABC`, but `x` and `e^{-x}` are in Computer Modern instead of CMU Bright.

Here is a sample document. It was compiled with xelatex, although a luatex-only solution would also be fine; I don't think pdflatex can handle fonts like this, but I'd love to be wrong. Any solution that works is acceptable.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setmainfont[
Path = /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
Extension = .ttf,
BoldFont = News Gothic MT Bold,
ItalicFont = News Gothic MT Italic,
BoldItalicFont = News Gothic MT Bold Italic
]
{News Gothic MT}

\setsansfont[
Path = /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
Extension = .ttf,
BoldFont = News Gothic MT Bold,
ItalicFont = News Gothic MT Italic,
BoldItalicFont = News Gothic MT Bold Italic
]
{News Gothic MT}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    This is math:
    \begin{align*}
        \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)e^{-x}}{x}\quad\textbf{\textit{ABC}}
    \end{align*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If I remove `\setmainfont`, then `sin` becomes Computer Modern as well. If I remove `\setsansfont`, then the body font and `ABC` both become CMU Bright (but `sin` remains News Gothic). But I can't figure out the combination that will result in:

1. Body font = News Gothic
2. `sin` = News Gothic (this is optional; CMU Bright would also be ok)
3. `\text` in math mode = News Gothic
4. Numbers, variables, etc in math mode = CMU Bright

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex or xetex

Comment: latex warns `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`TU/cmbr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using \`TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 144.`  which means there is no Unicode CM Bright so it's going to use Unicode Latin Modern instead.

Comment: Don't load `cmbright` if you want to use unicode fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use legacy math fonts, so don't load `unicode-math`. And, of course, don't load `fontenc` with T1 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{cmbright}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <--- don't

\setmainfont{News Gothic MT}[
  Path = /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  ItalicFont = * Italic,
  BoldFont = * Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic,
]

\setsansfont{News Gothic MT}[
  Path = /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  ItalicFont = * Italic,
  BoldFont = * Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic,
]

\begin{document}

This is math:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)e^{-x}}{x}\quad\textbf{\textit{ABC}}+123
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can get the operator names in News Gothic with a slightly different preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\setmainfont{News Gothic MT}[
  Path = /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  ItalicFont = * Italic,
  BoldFont = * Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic,
  NFSSFamily = ngmt,
]

\setsansfont{News Gothic MT}[
  Path = /Applications/Microsoft PowerPoint.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  ItalicFont = * Italic,
  BoldFont = * Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = * Bold Italic,
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{TU}{ngmt}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{TU}{ngmt}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmbroperators}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathSymbol{\std@equal}{\mathrel}{cmbroperators}{`=}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\show\Relbar

This is math:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)e^{-x}}{x}\quad\textbf{\textit{ABC}}+123
\end{equation*}

$\Longrightarrow\longrightarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll just note that this leads to `sin` being CMU Bright, but since that was optional, this does appear to be the correct answer.

Comment: @BallpointBen Added support for the operator names in News Gothic.

Comment: Thanks. This broke `\Longrightarrow` for me, since the left side is made up of an equals sign, which changes fonts.

Comment: @BallpointBen Fixed.